# while loop in R that will print the values of log(x) using this formula

Tags: r, while-loop, logarithm

I want to write an R while loop that
will print the values of log(x) using the formula

`log(x) = −0.076 + 0.281x −0.238/(x+0.15)`,

the built-in R function `log10`, and the absolute
difference between the two values, for the following values of x: `x = 0.1, 0.2, . . . , 0.9, 1.0`

My code is given below:

```
x <- seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1)
i <- 0
while(i < 10) {
  i <- i + 1
  LOG[i] <- -0.076 + 0.281*x[i] - 0.238/(x[i] + 0.15)
  lg[i] <- log10(x[i])
  ab[i] <- abs(lg[i] - LOG[i])
  cat("i = ", i, "LOG = ", LOG, "log = ", lg, "abs = ", ab, fill = TRUE)
}
```

But I have an error:

```
Error: object 'LOG' not found.
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to create object `LOG<-NULL`? 
Thank you

Comment: Before the loop write `LOG <- lg <- ab <- numeric(length(x))`. Also, please stop posting [code with lines starting with `>` and `+`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54970790/repeat-loop-in-r-to-compute-the-cosine-of-2-345-correct-to-5-decimal-places).

Comment: Suggestions: 1) In `cat`, just before `fill = TRUE`, put a newline character, `"\n"` to make the output more readable. 2) Why not a `for` loop? It seems waaaay more natural.

Comment: `LOG` needs to be defined before you can add elements to it

Comment: `NULL` is not an object---it is the absence of an object. `LOG <- NULL` is a nice way to remove `LOG` if it already exists. As Rui says, `LOG <- numeric(length(x))` is a good way to create an object (default will be all 0s).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to create objects `LOG`, `lg` and `ab` first.

**BUT** R has a great feature called vectorization that allows you to apply an operation to each element of vector at once (no need for looping). The code can go like this:

```
x <- seq(0.1, 1, by=0.1)
LOG <- -0.076+0.281*x-0.238/(x+0.15)
lg <- log10(x)
ab <- abs(lg - LOG)
```

Comment: Thank you. My assignment is designed to practice with looping, that is why I need to use while loop.